# I cannot pass a value on button click in oracle apex 19.2

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I have a wizard and i am trying to pass a value from one page to the next onclick a next button on the wizard in oracle apex but when i click next the value is not going through to the other side.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jv23L.png)

Image above shows the next button and the how i am trying to pass the value

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is this:

- there's page 33
- there are (at least) two items on that page

  - `P33_ID`
  - `P33_NEW`
- you are passing `P33_NEW` item's value into `P33_ID` item

  - in other words, you're doing it **on the same page**, while it seems - according to what you said ("I am trying to pass a value **from one page to the next**") - that you're expecting something to happen on some other page

If that's so, transfer `P33_NEW` item value to "some other page", not page 33.

If you still want to do it on the same page, consider using a **Set value** dynamic action.